# Periodical network downstream outage

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

Few weeks ago I started experiencing regular network outages.
With seemingly high accuracy **any** downstream operation is paused for ~1s every ~12s.

This experience goes along with what Task Manager shows during a Skype-call:
[image: Task Manager Ethernet Performance]

As you can see, downstream data rate drops to 0 regularly (1 grid cell width equals 4s).

Further things I know, found out or have tried so far:

- upstream is unaffected, as shown by Task Manager but also confirmed by Skype-counterparts who can hear me uninterrupted
- this also means that the network connection per se is not disrupted (downloads are also unaffected)
- also it is **not an issue of external hardware** I depend on (WiFi-router, ...) as it even affects downstream-connections against localhost! Sometimes I use Hyper-V virtual machines (running on the same PC), which you can connect to using Remote Desktop. The video signal (i.e. the stream I receive from my very own PC) is **also** paused in the same fashion
- neither Resource Monitor nor WireShark nor Event Viewer show suspicious/unexpected activity in those intervals
- booting a live-OS does not show the behavior, so I guess it is no hardware issue

Reinstalling Windows would probably resolve the issue, but as I did not find any useful resource concerning this weird issue, I thought it might be worth spreading and analyzing a little more first!

Comment: What security/firewall/antivirus software are you running?

Comment: Is this a wireless network connection?

Comment: Yes and no: it happens with the wireless connection but also - as mentioned - with all internal loopback traffic (wireless adapter can be deactivated entirely)

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: no 3rd-party tools, so Windows Firewall + Defender only (actually I have just tried deactivating them all, no difference)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably windows network driver problem. I had exactly same problem. Reinstall network driver. If this still happens after reinstall, try to install older version of driver.

Comment: which network driver? I have tried that with the WiFi-adapter and the Hyper-V adapter, no effect - actually I can uninstall them entirely, the problem still persists with loopback traffic! Is there a more fundamental driver I can play with than the device-drivers listed in devmgmt?